# RICOH Theta SのUSBストリーミングについて

Tags: android

現在、RICOHのTHETA Sを使用して、USB接続の360度のライブストリーミングアプリを作成しています。

THETAをMTPデバイスとして認識するところまではできたのですが、肝心のライブストリーミングに関するAPIがRICOHの仕様で見当たりません(HTTP APIではあるようですが、USB APIにはありません）。 
なにか、ほかのライブラリなどが必要なのかもしれませんが、それがわからず困っています。

なにか情報をお持ちの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけると幸いです。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/63981

Comment: マルチポスト　https://developers.theta360.com/ja/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=70